# How Can Insects Gain Gigantis?

Tags: biology, magic

So, it's time to bring about giant insects! How? [Gigantis!](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/201703/figuring-out-giganto) The one Enchantment that makes giant animals possible! Why? Because giant spiders and their ilk are a fantasy staple, and besides *why not?!*

The question, is **How Can Insects Gain Gigantis?**

The ways to gain Enchantments are as follows:

1. Use Natural Weaponry
   One way to get an Enchantment is to use one's own body (or parts of one's body) to kill the monster with the desired Enchantment. No, injuring it won't do, the magic will escape the killed cells and return to the still-living soul.
2. Lucky Sacrifice
   Another way to get an Enchantment is to be alive inside the monster with the desired Enchantment when it is killed. This would require an insect to get eaten by the Giganto, not to mention exposure to the Giganto's saliva or stomach acid (as this method is the inverse of "you are what you eat," AKA "you are what eats you").
3. Eating
   Eating part of the Giganto will grant a portion of its Enchantment to the consumer, especially if the flesh is fresh (read: still alive). However, this is a very inefficient method, as the Enchantment received is directly proportional to 1) how much you ate of the monster subtracted by 2) how much you actually digested the monster flesh.

Any insect using this method would have to gain the full Enchantment, eating an entire Giganto's worth of flesh or more (likely more) to succeed. Luckily, [Dropped](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/195344/preventing-dead-monsters-from-spawning-undead) meat doesn't lose potency, so flies have a decent shot at succeeding, as long as they can gain Gigantis within a single fly's lifespan *and* then reproduce.

4. Mimicry
   Plenty of insects eat bushes, so why not [Leafmaw](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/203909/explaining-leafmaw)? That should allow insects to gain their giant size from [Engulfers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/196989/gaining-the-engorgement-enchantment-for-peasants), when otherwise Engorgement would result in a gigantic corpse (ah, death by supersizing. Square-cube law, did you *have* to?).

**Specifications for Best Answer:**

1. The best answer will take each method and evaluate it to determine which would succeed and why.
2. The best answer will also determine which bugs will succeed using this method. Specific species aren't necessary; if you tell me flies will succeed and explain your reasoning, that will suffice. If you want help, feel free to search my various Gaining Enchantment questions to aid you. No, I can't answer this question myself, otherwise I wouldn't be asking! I'm no entomologist!

Comment: Quick question: is a roach infected with several parasitic wasps is swallowed by a poisonous frog which is then immediately swallowed by a baby giganto that dies  shortly from the poison, does that mean that we suddenly have to deal with giant roaches and colossal parasitic wasps?

Comment: @ProjectApex No, you get hellspawned frog-roach-3 wasps combo.https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/028/553/cover3.jpg

Comment: @ProjectApex you alive?

Comment: @Writer-of-stories I'd think so.

Comment: @ProjectApex: I'd say just the frog would gain Gigantis. The idea of a combo creature is intriguing though.....

Comment: @ProjectApex Ah, just expected a response earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Exponentially Growing Parasitic larvae.**

An insect that eats an Entire Giganto grows to the size of one. An  insect that eats 50% of the Giganto grows to 50% the size of one and so forth. That means any Giganto meat you eat gets converted into your own body mass with full efficiency.

So anything that feeds on the Giganto over a long period  grows quickly over that period. Being bigger in turn makes it eat faster, and the runaway effect makes it possible to eventually eat a large chunk of the grown animal

Giant insects begin when a paristic wasp or botfly injects an egg under the Giganto's skin. Let's say the larvae starts at 1 gram and can process its own body weight in flesh every day. Then by the end of day 1 the larva weights 2 grams. On day 2 it eats another 2 grams of flesh and grows to 4 grams. Every day it doubles in size. . . .

How quickly does it grow? The pattern says that after $n$ days the larva weighs $2^n$ grams. That means after two weeks on day 14 it weighs $2^{14} = 16438$ grams which is more than $16kg$ or the weight of small Springer Spaniel.

Likewise on day  $15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20$ days the larva weighs more than $32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1014$ kilos respecively. The last one is more than a tonne!

Comment: Ah, so it appears the parasites are the future of giant insects. What about scavengers, though?

Comment: @Alendyias The issue is a single animal can only digest the flesh so fast, and  there is a time limit before the entire carcass has been eaten by everything else.