# Rubberizing's Effects on Giant Caterpillars

Tags: biology, mythical-creatures, low-fantasy

**Giant caterpillars vs. Plops = Giant caterpillars > Plop**

It appears, since [giant caterpillars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/217348/feasibility-of-giant-caterpillar-archetypes) lack bones and possibly rigid parts in general, they could serve as a viable Plop predator despite Rubberization. If they do have rigid parts, well, so do people, and they can survive being Rubberized.

However, if giant caterpillars will become Rubberized, then I have to account for the effects of Rubberizing upon their biology. I've already determined that [for humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/196751/would-rubberizing-benefit-people-and-if-so-how?noredirect=1&lq=1), now I just need help determining how Rubberizing will affect giant caterpillars, the pros and cons of the Enchantment for them. So, my question is, **How Will Rubberization Affect Giant Caterpillars?**

**Or, if a clarification is needed, how would Rubberization be a benefit or detriment to giant caterpillars?**

**Further Clarification:**
The giant caterpillar link is simply there to give you an idea of the giant caterpillars in my world. It is *not* there because I want an answer addressing all of them. I'm good with one answer that addresses the pros and cons of Rubberization for a general giant caterpillar.

Comment: I count 6 cases based [on your examples](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/217348/feasibility-of-giant-caterpillar-archetypes) (and I'm not sure I counted all). The effects (benefits/disadvantages) for each of the species (and their habits) are going to be different - a runner (bendy legs make them in-effective runners) and a spitter (can increase the pressure/volume of the spat liquid). _Are you sure you want them under the hood of a single question?_ (asks me while the mouse pointer hovers undecided over the VTC linky)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: Oh no, thanks for letting me know about that! Okay, I'm good with just general examples, that's all I need. I can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem for your rubberized caterpillar is that its mouth parts are hard.  If they are rubberized, it can't bite its food (plant matter is tough) and will starve unless it can find anything that you could chew with your lips.

Comment: It could also swallow its food whole since they are quite large.

Comment: @LiveInAmbeR It would have to.  Either that or spit up digestive fluids and suck up the goo.  The trouble is that if it didn't evolve to eat that way, it won't automatically start eating that way without some further modification.  Also, the mouth parts won't have muscles in them to keep them rigid.  So it would be like eating with your lips after they've been hit with novacaine.

Comment: That. And there’s also the question about how the spell works on a living thing. If the caterpillars cells divide are they too rubberized or can it shed away the rubberized cells over a long time. If it metamorphoses what happens then? Alendyias will have to figure this out on their own.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, it appears I'll have to figure out if giant caterpillars can adapt to eat despite their new flexibility. Thank you!

Comment: @LiveInAmbeR: it's actually quite simple. An Enchantment alters a creature's essence, so new cells are Rubberized as well, and it's adult stage will be the same. Thanks for your comment, it lets me know where I need to go next!